# JPA Spring Boot postgresql : Insert data with the last ID

Tags: postgresql, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I have a MyClass entity with an auto increment id at the time of the project deployment I have an init.sql file to initialize the MY_CLASS table by adding two lines
the problem when I use my web service REST to insert a new line in the MY_CLASS table I have an error message of duplicate key of id 1 for the first click and id 2 on the second click but after the POST goes without problems. To solve this problem I can add the following line in my init.sql file

```
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_CLASS_id_seq RESTART WITH 3;
```

My question: How can I configure my POST to persist the data with the last id because whenever I can insert data with SQL.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "MY_CLASS")
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String label;

}



@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "clazz", path = "clazz")
public interface MyClassRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyClass, Long> {

}
```

init.sql

```
INSERT INTO public.MY_CLASS (label) values('label_1');
INSERT INTO public.MY_CLASS (label) values('label_2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you use the sequence generator, would you?

```
public class MyClass {
     public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "MY_CLASS_id_seq";

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE_NAME)
     @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME)
     private Long id;

     @NotNull
     private String label;
}
```

Comment: your proposal solved my problem just the id jumped to 50 instead of using the last id 3. i do not understand why 50 and if i initialize my database with 50 lines in init.sql file would not ask problem

Comment: When Hibernate uses sequence generator it doesn't fetch the sequence value every time. Instead of it grabs a number of ids (50 by default) and manages them itself. Anyway you shouldn't worry if every number of sequence is used and there are gaps between them.